# How to use search and left function in Excel for multiple line of text

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

Good day,

I have a String as follow:

```
DL_MST_BOND.MST_MASTER
DL_MST_SP.MST_MASTER
DL_MST_UT.MST_MASTER
```

As you can see, this string having 3 line, and each line having a "." in between.

I would like to write a function in excel to only retrieve the first String on each line, so the value will be

```
DL_MST_BOND
DL_MST_SP
DL_MST_UT
```

May I know what function I can do to achieve this?

Actually my end result to make the string like this:

```
DL_MST_BOND,DL_MST_SP,DL_MST_UT
```

But I know that if I can get done on first step, then I am able to do the replace to reach my final result.

[image]

Using this formula but getting error. please help.

Comment: Panadol Chong if you you have the same pattern at the end of the string -".MST_MASTER" this formula will work in excel 2019
=TEXTJOIN(",",,TRANSPOSE(LEFT(A1:A3,SEARCH(".MST",A1:A3)-1)))

Answer (score 0):

Use below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,TEXTBEFORE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,CHAR(10)),"."))&CHAR(34)
```

For ***Excel-2019*** you may give a try this array formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,LEFT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),SEARCH(".",FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))-1))&CHAR(34)
```

Array formulas needs to enter by pressing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Harun, may I know does it only apply to certain excel version?
I am using Microsoft Office 2019, but hitting #NAME? error for this formula. Attached screen shot in question.

Comment: @PanadolChong Yes, it is only available to `Microsoft-365`.

Comment: @PanadolChong Would please try my edited answer second formula.

Comment: Maybe shorten this a bit: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"."),".","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 =1]"))`

Comment: @JvdV Yes, it is shorter. Let get feedback from OP.